# xpath why i got empty result in this expth

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I try this xpath

```
.//div[@class='owl-wrapper']
```

on this webiste

http://www.justproperty.com/search/uae/apartments/filter__cid/0/sort/score__desc/per_page/20/page/1

but i got empty result, though i can see it in the Google F12 developer tool.

you may think that this is a javascript call, but it is not because, i am using scrapy and i can `view` the response like this:

```
scrapy shell ("website")
view(response)
```

and that class is there.

help please

Screenshot from my Chrome for the page that comes using view(response)

[image: Screenshot from my Chrome for the page that comes using view(response)]

Comment: I repeated your `scrapy` commands but can't see that `class` value.

Comment: @Birei I didn't get you sorry, did you mean that you agree with me too?

Comment: @Birei the class is there when you use [Google Chrome F1 Developer Tool](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools)

Comment: I checked the source code of the `hmtl` page resulted from the `view(response)` command and I didn't see any `owl-wrapper` value. My browser is Firefox, but I don't think it makes any difference in this case.

Comment: @Birei I updated my question adding a screenshot from my Chrome for the html resulted from `view(response)`

Comment: `.//` is shorthand for `./descendant-or-self::`, meaning "the current node or any descendant of the current node", so the million dollar question is: what is the context in which you evaluate this expression?

Comment: @biziclop when you use scrapy, the `.//` means any node inside the html, the `.//` starts from the very very first node

Comment: @biziclop forgot about scrapy please, the question is about xpath, you can use whatever tool you like in order to check if that class exists or not. it is up to you to use any tool, the important to me is the xpath code

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli Fair enough, I'm not familiar with scrapy, only XPath in general. I'd still try `//div[@class='owl-wrapper']` just to see what happens. This is supposed to search from the root element regardless of the current node.

Comment: @biziclop if you meant to remove the `dot`, I did try that and the result is the same with or without `dot`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is: search results which include the `div` element with `owl-wrapper` class are **loaded asynchronously with an additional GET request**.

You need to simulate this request in your code, example using `requests`:

```
import requests

with requests.Session() as session:
    session.get('http://www.justproperty.com/search/uae/apartments/filter__cid/0/sort/score__desc/per_page/20/page/1')

    params = {
        'url': 'filter__cid/0/sort/score__desc/per_page/20/page/1',
        'ajax': 'true'
    }
    response = session.get('http://www.justproperty.com/search/featured-properties/', params=params)
    results = response.json()

    for result in results:
        print result['description']
```

Prints:

```
2 bedroom unit on high floor. Full Fountain View,It comes with different amenities, facilities and hotel services. It is located in a prime location, The Address Hotel Lake Downtown. This property is...
Large Upgraded 1 Bedroom For Sale In Index Tower DIFC With DIFC ViewSize: 840 square feet - 78 square metersBedroom: 1 Bathroom: 1 plus guest washroomKitchen: Fully Equipped modern style kitchen with...
Spacious and nice 1-bedroom apartment for
...
```

---

Example `Scrapy` spider based on the provided above solution:

```
import json

import scrapy


class JustPropertySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "justproperty"
    allowed_domains = ["justproperty.com"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://www.justproperty.com/search/uae/apartments/filter__cid/0/sort/score__desc/per_page/20/page/1"
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        yield scrapy.Request('http://www.justproperty.com/search/featured-properties/?url=filter__cid/0/sort/score__desc/per_page/20/page/1&ajax=true',
                             callback=self.parse_results,
                             headers={'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'})

    def parse_results(self, response):
        results = json.loads(response.body)

        for result in results:
            print result['description']
```

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli it is not a scrapy code, it is python+requests, but 1. The point marked in bold is the most important here 2. you can translate the code into scrapy by using `scrapy.http.Request`.

Comment: i couldn't find such an option to anable the ajax calls in Scrapy, could you give me a reference or link please? many thanks

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli okay, yup, the trick would be to provide necessary headers I think. I'll try to provide you with a scrapy-specific solution later today. Thanks for coming back on this one.

Comment: Thanks for your help, i accept your answer for sure, I already find these links https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/getting-started that might be helpful , but i am trying to invest more time in it https://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html?highlight=ajax#module-scrapy.contrib.downloadermiddleware.ajaxcrawl

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli please see the example spider in the updated answer. Hope that helps to get started.

Comment: your solution gives me the result not in html form, but in json format. I would like to have an html format in order to continue my parsing. is there a solution please?

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli yup, since this is an ajax XHR request simulation - in order to achieve and HTML result, your best bet would be to involve a real browser (a headless phantomjs is also an option). But, as a downside, you'll make your web-scraping much slower.